# Sails.js custom error types?

Tags: sails.js

I am currently building a Sails.js app. I am using promises in my controllers. I would like to define a set of custom error objects to simplify error propagation. Where do you define custom error objects so that they are accessible between controllers and services files?

For examples:

*CustomErrors.js: **(Where is the best place for custom errors to be defined?)***

```
function ErrorNotFound(message) {
  this.name = 'Error Not Found';
  this.message = message || 'Not Found';
    this.status = 404;
  this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}
ErrorNotFound.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
ErrorNotFound.prototype.constructor = ErrorNotFound;
```

*Controller1.js:*

```
Model.find({attr1: 123, name: 'Joe Blogs}).then(function(model){
  if(!model) throw new ErrorNotFound("The specified model was not found");
  else return Model2.find({uuid: req.uuid, colour: model.favourite_colour});
})then(function(model2){
  return res.json(model2);
}).catch(function(err){
  //if ErrorNotFound is caught, it will return Not Found 404
  //otherwise it will return ServerError 500
  res.negotiate(err); 
})
```

Comment: Did you get an answer for this from elsewhere? Where did you place `CustomErrors.js` finally?